# Where can I ask about control systems?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have questions about control systems using [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), designing controllers, understanding the meaning of root locus case and so on.

Where can I ask about it?

Comment: "Control system" is an awfully broad term. This is essentially the same as asking "where can I ask about computers". Well, it depends...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Robotics SE](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) claims to accept control system questions. Check their [Help Center](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or ask on their [Meta site](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/). 
This came up recently because a user there claimed that a proposal to create a Control Systems site is a duplicate of Robotics SE.

> Flag:
>   Control Systems Technology
>   Duplicate of [Robotics.se](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) "We ask and answer questions about robotics, control systems, control theory, algorithms, actuators and sensors."

Comment: I will give it a try thanks

Answer (score -1):

I suggest Engineering StackExchange: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/